# GWT / GXT ClassCastException

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, gxt

This is going to be lengthy.

**Disclaimer**: this specifically is work code I inherited from a predecessor, so I don't know why certain parts are coded as such, only that they are. This is on top of me not fully understanding the intention, as well as some of the syntax used, hence this post. If possible, I rather not edit anything outside of the primary file causing the issue.
(I've gotten enough replies asking why my code is written as such without answering the question that it kinda annoys me)

The base function of the program is to read from a SQL table and populate it to a screen. The user can then edit a couple of fields and update it; saving it to the database for future reference, or to create a new entry into the database.

From what I'm understanding:-

- Create: creates a new entry in Table A.
- Edit: creates a new entry in Table B based on the Table A data.
- Saving the Edit: the data from Table B will be used to *replace* the data in Table A.

Both Table A and Table B, while different overall, have some similar columns that are used as reference to each other(not explicitly defined)

**The program has been working fine usually, but when I changed the datatype for a specific  column in Table B from *int* to *bigint* and access the edit screen of an existing data, I start getting an exception message and the function breaks(though the overall program still works).**

**The error message only appears in the browser console log, pointing to a line in the cache.html. This error persist in 2 separate browsers, both Chrome and (IE Mode) Edge.**

[image]

Table A also has a similar column, declared as *int* and the stored procedures usually reference this in the queries, so I thought there might be some conversion issue, but even after converting the datatype for both columns in both tables to *bigint*, the error still persist.

After further checking, the issue *only* happens when the datatype for the column in Table B is changed from *int* to *bigint*. When I try to change the related column in Table A from from *int* to *bigint* to match(without changing the datatype for the column in Table B), there isn't any issue.

On top of Java, the codebase is also using GWT (2.4) to populate the screen, the (edited) related code includes:

Client-Side:

```
private StackTraceElement[] newResult;
    protected void setNewStackTrace(StackTraceElement[] result){
        Log.debug("Ex setNewStackTrace! " + result);
        newResult = result;
    }
protected void buildScreen() {
    
    try {
        GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new
             GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
             public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
                Log.debug("Ex caught!", e);
                Log.debug("Ex getCause: ", e.getCause());
                try {               <Service>.Util.getInstance().getDeobfuscateStackTrace(e.getStackTrace(), new AsyncCallback<StackTraceElement[]>() {
                        public void onSuccess(StackTraceElement[] result) {
                            setNewStackTrace(result);
                        }
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                            WidgetUtils.handleError(caught);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (ApplicationException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.debug("Ex ApplicationException: ", e1);
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.setStackTrace(newResult);
            }
         });

        prepareGrid();
        (...)
        prepareMainButtons();
        (...)
        prepareFormBinding();
        (...)
        });
        layout();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppsUtil.handleError(e);
    }
}

(...)
private DbQuery QUERY = new DbQuery();
private PagingGridHelper<BaseModel> grid;
private String SELECTED_REPORT;
private Boolean LOADED = false;

private void prepareGrid() {
    try {
        QUERY.set_auditDbTable("<SQL Table>");
        QUERY.setTableName("<Stored Procedure>");

        List<ColumnConfig> columns = getColumns();
        
        RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<? extends ModelData>> proxy = new RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<? extends ModelData>>() {
                protected void load(Object loadConfig, AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<? extends ModelData>> callback) {
                    
                    if (SELECTED_REPORT == null) {
                        if (LOADED)
                        callback.onSuccess(new BasePagingLoadResult<BaseModel>( new ArrayList<BaseModel>() ));
                    } else {
                        FilterPagingLoadConfig conf = (FilterPagingLoadConfig) loadConfig;
                        DbQueryService.Util.getInstance().selectPage(QUERY, conf, callback);
                    }
                }
        };

        (...)
        String columnData="";
        for (int x=0; x<columns.size();x++){
            columnData+=columns.get(x).getHeader() + ", ";
        }
        grid =  new PagingGridHelper<BaseModel>(QUERY, columns, proxy, DOWNLOAD, false);
        (...)
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppsUtil.handleError(e);
    }
}

private void prepareMainButtons() throws Exception {
    (...)
    EDIT = SWUtil.createButton(SWButton.EDIT);
    EDIT.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {
        public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {
            (...)
            if (grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().size() == 1) {
                (...)
                switchMode(Mode.DataEdit, false);
                // related to issue
                formBinding.bind((BaseModel) grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().get(0)); 
            }
        }
    });

    (...)
}


private void prepareFormBinding() {
    try{
    formBinding = new FormBinding(EditorForm, true);
    formBinding.setStore(new ListStore<BaseModel>());

    formBinding.addListener(Events.BeforeBind, new Listener<BindingEvent>() {
        public void handleEvent(BindingEvent be) {
            forceReset();
            deselectAllCurrency();
            EditorForm.reset();
            (...)
        }
    });

    formBinding.addListener(Events.Bind, new Listener<BindingEvent>() {
        (...)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    formBinding.addListener(Events.UnBind, new Listener<BindingEvent>() {
        (...)
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}


public PagingGridHelper(DbQuery dquery, List<ColumnConfig> uColumns, RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<? extends ModelData>> uproxy, final BaseDownload download, boolean checkable) {
        this.query = dquery;
        this.columns = uColumns;
        this.proxy = uproxy;
        this.checkable = checkable;
        
        try {
            if (query == null)
                query = new DbQuery();
            
            (...)
            columnModel = new ColumnModel(columns);


            if (proxy == null) {
                proxy = new RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<? extends ModelData>>() {
                    protected void load(Object loadConfig, AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<? extends ModelData>> callback) {
                        FilterPagingLoadConfig conf = (FilterPagingLoadConfig) loadConfig;
                        DbQueryService.Util.getInstance().selectAsPage(query, conf, callback);
                    }
                };
            }
            
            loadConfig = new BaseFilterPagingLoadConfig(0, pageSize);
            loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<D>>(proxy) {
                protected Object newLoadConfig() {
                    return loadConfig;
                }
            };

            loader.setRemoteSort(true);
            loader.setReuseLoadConfig(true);

            store = new ListStore<D>(loader);
            store.addListener(Store.DataChanged, new Listener<StoreEvent<? extends ModelData>>() {
                public void handleEvent(StoreEvent<? extends ModelData> be) {
                    for (ModelData d : store.getModels()) {
                        (...)
                    }
                }
            });

            (...)
            
            grid = new Grid<D>(store, columnModel);
            (...)
            grid.setLoadMask(true);
            grid.setBorders(true);
            
            (...)
            
            grid.addListener(Events.Attach, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
                public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
                    loader.load(0, pageSize);
                }
            });
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GWT.log(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Server-side:

```
@Override
    public StackTraceElement[] getDeobfuscateStackTrace(StackTraceElement[] e) throws ApplicationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StackTraceDeobfuscator testDeobfuscator = new StackTraceDeobfuscator("war/WEB-INF/deploy/<project>/symbolMaps/");
        String strongName = request.getHeader(RpcRequestBuilder.STRONG_NAME_HEADER);
        return testDeobfuscator.deobfuscateStackTrace(e, strongName);
    }
```

After a long while, I think I managed to pinpoint to the *where* of the issue:

```
formBinding.bind((BaseModel) grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().get(0));
```

which seems to relate to this (to be precise, this part does not hit)

```
formBinding.addListener(Events.Bind, new Listener<BindingEvent>() {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void handleEvent(BindingEvent be) {
        (...)
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I still do not know the *why*, as well as *how* to solve it. Any ideas?

As mentioned, the **only** thing changed was the data type of a specific column in Table B. Else, the overall program is working as expected, in both Chrome and (IE Mode) Edge.

*Edit 28/7/2023*

Read through the GWT documentation, and trying to make sense of Exception thrown.

I got this as a result of the addition of the `GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` above:

*Edit 4/8/2023* Update exception image after implementing `<style>PRETTY</style>` in the `pom.xml`.

[image]

*Edit 7/8/2023* Update exception image after implementing `<style>DETAILED</style>` in the `pom.xml`.

[image]

As well as adding the following in my .gwt.xml file:

[image]

And the following to my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/<project>/remote_logging</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Some context that might help - this is GXT 1.x or 2.x, and also an old version of GWT. You almost certainly shouldn't need emulated stack mode, it will make reading the obf code far more difficult, and roughly double the size of the output - all modern browsers support native stack mode. Instead consider the server-side stack trade deobfuscator, or compile with style=PRETTY so the output is sorta-kinda readable (and you can debug more easily). I don't think there is enough detail in your question to help - likely in PagingGridHelper or one of its params is the key that is missing.

Comment: I dont believe GWT is the cause of my primary error, so I went over it, just mentioning in passing. Regardless, Ive updated the post to include how I (attempted to) implement the GWT exception, resulting in the log. I wasnt sure what worked, so I threw everything in and hoped to learn from the results.

Comment: As mentioned, the only change I did was an SQL Alter on the db side, nothing in the code was changed. So, trying to pinpoint the source of the exception is my current grief.

Comment: Understood, but I'm asking these questions to understand what the app is doing such that this error is happening from such a simple change. My hunch is that changing the sql schema changed the wire format (the proxy+query fetched the data?), which altered how the store was loaded (the PagingGridHelper likely holds this or points at it), which made that cast to ModelData invalid.

Comment: I was reading through the codes based on what you mentioned; still cant figure it out. Not sure where and when this "wire format" you speak of is defined., not helping that I dont really understand how the gwt store and load process works exactly. Hence, I've updated the post to include the codes related to RPCProxy, as well as the related PagingGridHelper constructor.

Comment: The updated stack trace helps - can you ask your browser debugger to pause on exceptions so you can see what value is being used that fails the cast in that `getStringValue` method, or in `dynamicCast` itself, so we can see the expected vs actual types (and the value, possibly where it came from)? Other possibly necessary code, the contents of `selectAsPage(query, conf, callback)` to see what it is doing to actually create the objects and pass to the callback.

Comment: No, I cant pause. Could be because its an older version, but GWT does not allow dev mode(it doesnt even run on Chrome well, but that could be a side-effect of the project as a whole.), hence why I've been debugging through logging, on Edge using IE Mode and the IEChooser. I've also been trying to figure out the actual type of the return value as well that's not the generic ```Number``` (why does Java not have a ```getType()``` of sorts. ```instanceof``` is not a good enough replacement). Will try to reconfirm ```selectAsPage``` output.

Comment: No, not legacy dev mode, using the browser dev tools - IE and Edge have these as well. Try putting a breakpoing inside the dynamicCast where it throws, for example. JS only has a `number` type, but Java has distinct differences between Integer/Long/Double etc, so GWT emulates them all differently (recent versions of GWT use JS number for Double, and the rest are emulated). This back-and-forth doesn't really belong in comments, consider joining us at https://matrix.to/#/#gwtproject_gwt:gitter.im or https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt (same chat, just different ways to join) for actual chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended in the comments, I went and checked in detail on the
`selectAsPage` function.

After walking through the codes from it, it turns out the issue is related to one of the utility functions that handle and converts the results read from the db query into a more standardized java data.

```
public static <D extends BaseModel> void processRow(ResultSet rs, List<D> rows, D model) throws SQLException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if (model == null)
            model = (D) new BaseModel();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() ; i++) {
            String column = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
            if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.INTEGER) {
                model.set(column, rs.getInt(i) );
            }
            else if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.BIGINT) {
                model.set(column, rs.getBigDecimal(i).toBigInteger() );
            } 
            else if(rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.NVARCHAR) {
                model.set(column, rs.getString(i));
            } else if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                model.set(column, Misc.getTimestamp(rs, i) );
            } else if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.FLOAT) {
                model.set(column, new Double( rs.getFloat(i)) );
            } else if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.DOUBLE) {
                model.set(column, new Double( rs.getFloat(i)) );
            } else if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.DECIMAL) {
                Double d  = new Double( rs.getDouble(i) );
                model.set(column, d.doubleValue() );
            } else if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.BIT) {
                model.set(column, rs.getInt(i) );
            } else {
                model.set(column, rs.getString(i) );
            }
            sb.append(column + "=" + rs.getString(i) + "; type=" + rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i));
        }
        rows.add( model );
```

Specifically, this section originally didnt exist.

```
else if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) == Types.BIGINT) {
                    model.set(column, rs.getBigDecimal(i).toBigInteger() );
                }
```

Thus the code could not properly handle `BigInt` values; as a result defaulting the value as `String`, which will eventually lead to the aforementioned `ClassCastException` issue.

Once I added this code chunk(and modified a few stuffs here and there to cater for it), the issue more or less disappeared.

This frustratingly took me way too long to pinpoint.